# Optimising Regular Expression and Iterating Over Regex Match Groups

Tags: c#, regex

> **Thank you for the answers guys! This is what i went with which is perfect.**
>
> ```
> var m4ny = new Regex(@"(?<Name>[^\(]*collection\s?)(?<Year>\([^\)]*\))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
> var m4y = new Regex(@"\b(19|20)[0-9]{2}\b");
> if (m4ny.IsMatch(fn) && m4y.IsMatch(fn)) return "[M4] " + UcWords(removeDomains(m4ny.Match(fn).Groups[@"Name"].Value)) + " (" + string.Join(@", ", m4y.Matches(fn).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)) + ")";
> ```

The following C# code works fine but its totally awful and i know there will be much better ways to do it, if it were PHP i could easily condense but this is the extent of my c# knowlege, any pointers welcome.

```
Regex r4 = new Regex("(?<Name>.*)\\((?<Year>[-, ]*(20|19)[0-9]{2}[-, ]*)*\\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m4 = r4.Match(fn);

if (fn.ToLower().Contains("collection") && m4.Success)
{
    string years = "";
    Group g = m4.Groups["Year"];
            
    CaptureCollection cc = g.Captures;
    for (int j = 0; j < cc.Count; j++)
    {
        Capture c = cc[j];
        years = years + c.Value.Replace(",", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "") + ", ";
    }

    return "[M4] " + UcWords(removeDomains(m4.Groups["Name"].Value).Replace('.', ' ').Replace(",", "").Replace(":", "").Replace("  ", " ").ToLower()).Trim() + " (" + years.Substring(0,years.Length - 2) + ")";
}
```

This particular piece of code basically matches:

```
Anything written    hERE collEction (1928, 1957- 1977,1989    2001)
```

and returns:

```
Anything Written Here Collection (1928, 1957, 1977, 1989, 2001)
```

I thinking that with a better regex there would be no need pull the string apart and glue it back together, either that or there must be a tidier way of interating over the group of matches (ideally in one statement.)

Thanks!
Dean.

Comment: I think the best way to start this question is explain your problem and the requirements. Although the code a is good start, maybe if we could understand the exact nature of the problem a more efficient suitable approach maybe tendered. The multiple white spaces are easy to fix, however, the format requires a domain, that's to say, if you can explain how badly formatted this data can be (to a finite degree), there might be a better solution. For instance, is the only problem that the collection sometimes is missing commas / consistent spaces ? what's the nature of that minus sign... ect?

Comment: The word collection has to be there to apply this “filter” to it, there are 7 in total but i am happy with the others, the minus comma or space are just possible separators.

Comment: So you have mutated the start of the string ? and fixed the case... this is not represented in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dean,

Sometimes I find it's easier to just break things up into two expressions. The below gets you what you're after and may offer some of the simplicity you were hoping for:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

private string FindAndCleanDateStrings()
{
    var fn = @"Anything written    hERE collEction (1928, 1957- 1977,1989    2001)";
    var rxNameYear = new Regex(@"(?<Name>[^\(]*collection\s?)(?<Year>\([^\)]*\))",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var rxYears = new Regex(@"\b(19|20)[0-9]{2}\b");

    //Validate
    if (!rxNameYear.IsMatch(fn) || !rxYears.IsMatch(fn)) return null;

    //Clean up <Name>
    var textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
    var name = textInfo.ToTitleCase(rxNameYear.Match(fn).Groups[@"Name"].Value.Trim().ToLower());
    name = Regex.Replace(name, @"\s+", " ");

    //Return and print completed string.
    var newStr = $@"{name} ({string.Join(@", ",rxYears.Matches(fn).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value))})";
    Console.WriteLine(newStr);
    return newStr;
}
```

The above returns: "Anything Written Here Collection (1928, 1957, 1977, 1989, 2001)"

Answer (score -1):

If you are just interested in the collection, it might be more efficient to just `Split` and `Join` (the assumption being you don't need any more validation).

**Given**

```
private static readonly Regex _regex = new Regex(@"(?<=collEction\s\().*(?=\))", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

private static string FormatString(string input)
{
   var match = _regex.Match(input);

   if (!match.Success) return input;

   var values = match.Value.Split(new[] {',', '-', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   return _regex.Replace(input, string.Join(", ", values));
}
```

**Usage**

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
   "Anything written    hERE collEction (1928, 1957- 1977,1989    2001)",
   "Anything written hERE collEction (1928, 1957- 1977,1989    2001)",
   "Anything written  hERE ColLeCtIon (1928,,, 1957- ---1977,     1989   2001)",
};


foreach (var item in list.Select(FormatString))
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output**

```
Anything written    hERE collEction (1928, 1957, 1977, 1989, 2001)
Anything written hERE collEction (1928, 1957, 1977, 1989, 2001)
Anything written  hERE ColLeCtIon (1928, 1957, 1977, 1989, 2001)
```

<sub>***Note** : You could also do this O(n) parsing the string once, without regex, using `Span<char>`, a few `if` statements and a slice, which would be the most efficient yet less maintainable and forgiving. Though any solution really depends on your specific needs (including this one)*</sub>

An example of how that might look

```
private static string FormatString2(string input)
{
   var span = input.AsSpan();
   var match = "collection (".AsSpan();
   Span<char> result = stackalloc char[input.Length + 10];
   var hasSpace = false;

   for (int i = 0, j = 0, index = 0; i < span.Length; i++)
   {
      if (index < match.Length)
      {
         if (char.ToLower(span[i]) == match[index]) index++;
         else if (index >= 0) index = 0;
         result[j++] = span[i];
         if (index <= match.Length) continue;
      }

      if (span[i] >= '0' && span[i] <= '9')
      {
         result[j++] = span[i];
         hasSpace = false;
         continue;
      }

      if (span[i] == ')')
      {
         result[j++] = span[i];
         return new string(result);
      }

      if (hasSpace) continue;

      hasSpace = true;
      result[j++] = ',';
      result[j++] = ' ';
   }

   return input;
}
```

**Output**

```
Anything written    hERE collEction (1928, 1957, 1977, 1989, 2001)
Anything written hERE collEction (1928, 1957, 1977, 1989, 2001)
Anything written  hERE ColLeCtIon (1928, 1957, 1977, 1989, 2001)
```

I don't really promote using this method unless you absolutely need the performance with all the limitations it has